# clearTimeout(timer) not taken into account - New timer variable created each time

Tags: javascript, settimeout, slideshow, cleartimeout

In the current slideshow I'm building, I use a timer variable to rotate the slides automatically every 4s. Since manual controls are also present, **I wanted to reset this timer whenever the controls are used** to avoid any premature succession between two slides, but didn't manage to do it.

I supposed it to be a scope problem, but the timer variable is out of the functions that are trying to share it (*showSlide(n) and changeSlide(n)*). Yet **a brand new timer variable seems to be created each time the changeSlide function is called** : the slides automatic rotation quickens each time the "next" control is used, as if multiple timeouts were calling the function simultaneously. What is wrong here ?

```
const slideshows = document.getElementsByClassName("js-slideshow");
[].forEach.call(slideshows, function(slideshow) {
  slideshowlize(slideshow);
});

function slideshowlize(slideshow){
  const desc = slideshow.getElementsByClassName("js-desc");
  const slide = slideshow.getElementsByClassName("js-slide");
  let timer;
  let index = 0;
  const slidePrev = slideshow.querySelector('.js-prev');
  const slideNext = slideshow.querySelector('.js-next');

  function showSlide(n){  
    clearTimeout(timer); // This one is not used yet
    if(n < 0){
      n = slide.length -1;
    }
    else if(n > slide.length -1){
      n = 0;
    }
    let i;
    for(i = 0; i < slide.length; i++){
      slide[i].classList.remove("is-shown");
    }
    for(i = 0; i < desc.length; i++){
      desc[i].classList.remove("is-shown");
    }
    slide[n].classList.add("is-shown");
    desc[n].classList.add("is-shown");
    index = n;
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
      changeSlide(1);
    }, 4000);
  }

  function changeSlide(n){ // this is where the magic doesn't happen
    clearTimeout(timer);
    if (n > 0){
      showSlide(index += 1);
    } else {
      showSlide(index -= 1);
    }
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
      changeSlide(1);
    }, 4000);
  }
  showSlide(index);
  slidePrev.addEventListener('click', function(){
    changeSlide(-1);
  });
  slideNext.addEventListener('click', function(){
    changeSlide(1);
  });
}
```

Edit : Two different timers were set up. Since showSlide(n) were already resetting the timer, changeSlide(n) had no need to do it too. Thanks to Bergi for pointing it out.

```
     function changeSlide(n){
        //removed "clearTimeout(timer);"
          if (n > 0){
           showSlide(index += 1);
          } else {
           showSlide(index -= 1);
          }
      
        //removed "timer = setTimeout(...);"
      }
```

Comment: What convinced you that a new `timer` variable is being created?

Comment: Each time the controls are used, the slides rotate a bit quicker. I therefore supposed that multiple timeouts were running simultaneously. I edited my post with this (important) precision, thank you.

Comment: Both of your `showSlide` and `changeSlide` function do clear and set a timeout - only one of them should! `changeSlide` is calling `showSlide` which creates one timer, then it adds another timer itself

Comment: You're completely right Bergi, and you solved my problem, thank you.